# Does snappy packaging make a convenient, portable, offline MediaWiki possible (say, on a thumb drive)?

Tags: usb-drive, ubuntu-core, mediawiki

I LOVE MediaWiki, and would love to have one as a personal wiki solution on a thumb drive. There seem to be solutions for this on Windows, via XAMP. But from what I can tell, linux does not allow this.

Now that snaps are here, I am wondering if they make such a technology more accessible.

How does one go about creating a portable, offline Mediawiki, on -- say -- a thumb drive? (I apologize, because I realize this forum could be the wrong place if this has nothing to do with snaps.)

Thank you for any direction on this ahead of time.

Comment: Snaps are just isolated apps that come with dependencies pre-packaged. I don't think they're what you want.

Comment: I think this should be absolutely doable. Check out [Kyle Fazzari's post about snapping NextCloud](https://kyrofa.com/posts/installing-nextcloud-can-be-a-snap), about how a whole stack can be put into a snap. What I'm a bit unsure about is what you want to do with the thumb drive. Do you want to save data there and use it in another set-up? Do you want to have the entire system (including Ubuntu Core) on the thumb drive? Which workflow do you envision?

Comment: If necessary, the drive could be dedicated to the wiki, but I envision something that would be cross-computer.  I would like it to persist seemlessly between linux installations.

Comment: The workflow would be I plug the drive into a machine and [after looking at NextCloud] perhaps just typing in a url and having my wiki show up to read and edit with a password as per an online one.

Comment: I will try to work that on my own. The idea is a turn-key, portable, offline web app. Probably not a huge 'market' for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Kiwix](http://www.kiwix.org/) for offline read-only MediaWiki snapshots. If you want a proper functional MediaWiki, probably the least painful way to go about it is [MediaWiki-Vagrant](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki-Vagrant) - create the wiki on a virtual machine and save a snapshot of that virtual machine on a stick. (This will have a huge size and performance overhead but with typical CPUs and USB stick sizes these days that's not much of a problem.) You will still have to install the software which runs the virtual machine ([Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) and [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) on the real machine, but there are OS packages for that.

Comment: Thanks. That was my fear, but it answers my question.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just do a normal install with the stick as install directory, but then you will have to change the web server configuration on the target machine to map some URL to the stick. (Not to mention that PHP version, DB version, whatever else has to be right.)

Comment: Very, very alternatively you can put an executable web server on the stick and have it listen on some non-standard port, and bundle all other executables needed (PHP, MySQL etc), which is basically what XAMPP does. I think it would require significantly more effort than installing vagrant, so unless you are specifically looking for a solution that can be installed on an offline computer, you are better off doing that.